Why does my R recursive function work this way?
Read recently that for a function programming language like R, recursion is preferred to iteration. I tried implementing this principle with a function called recur whose sole aim is to take 2 arguments (x, y), increase x until it gets to y, and return a vector x y.
Using a few print statements to check the flow, I found that, while the program works without errors and x is indeed increased to the value of y, the return statement at the end produces a different output. Here's the code and the corresponding output:
recur <- function(x, y) {
    # 1st code block
    print("start")
    if (x < y) {
       print('before') # 1st print statement to check control flow
       x <- x + 1
       recur(x, y)
    }

    # 2nd code block
    print('return block') # 2nd print statement to check control flow
    print('here again') # 3rd print statement to check control flow
    return (c(x, y))
}

OUTPUT
> recur(0, 5)
[1] "start"
[1] "before"
[1] 1
[1] "start"
[1] "before"
[1] 2
[1] "start"
[1] "before"
[1] 3
[1] "start"
[1] "before"
[1] 4
[1] "start"
[1] "before"
[1] 5
[1] "start"
[1] "return block"
[1] "here again"
[1] "return block"
[1] "here again"
[1] "return block"
[1] "here again"
[1] "return block"
[1] "here again"
[1] "return block"
[1] "here again"
[1] "return block"
[1] "here again"
[1] 1 5

DESIRED OUTPUT
> recur(0, 5)
[1] "start"
[1] "before"
[1] 1
[1] "start"
[1] "before"
[1] 2
[1] "start"
[1] "before"
[1] 3
[1] "start"
[1] "before"
[1] 4
[1] "start"
[1] "before"
[1] 5
[1] "start"
[1] "return block"
[1] "here again"
[1] 5 5

Why did it iterate over the second block of code even if there are no iterative statements in that block? And given the input argument 0, 5, why is it returning 1 5 instead of 5 5?

Your desired output cannot be achieved unless you print outside of the recursive function. Note that the recursive function is called 6 times. Thus every print statement inside the function must be printed 6 times. That's true to every other function regardless of its nature.  If you want the desired output, wrap the recursive function with another function and the print outside the recursive portion

Your function never prints “start”. Please post the actual code and output, not merely something similar.

The problem with your code is that the value of x returned from each iteration is not stored and the rules of variable scope in R result in the x in each call to recur being a different variable. That is, each recur() has its own x and incrementing that x does not affect the value of the x in the recur() that was called previously. The first recur() calls the other recurs, but it has already incremented its x and it is unaware that the other recurs increment their own x. When the final return is executed, the x of that recur is still 1 and that is what you see.
Compare these two versions of recur, where the second one stores the returned value.
recur <- function(x, y) {
  # 1st code block
  if (x < y) {
    print('before') # 1st print statement to check control flow
    x <- x + 1
    recur(x, y)
  }
  
  # 2nd code block
  print(paste('return block', 'x= ',x)) # 2nd print statement to check control flow
  print('here again') # 3rd print statement to check control flow
  return (c(x, y))
}

recur(0,5)
#> [1] "before"
#> [1] "before"
#> [1] "before"
#> [1] "before"
#> [1] "before"
#> [1] "return block x=  5"
#> [1] "here again"
#> [1] "return block x=  5"
#> [1] "here again"
#> [1] "return block x=  4"
#> [1] "here again"
#> [1] "return block x=  3"
#> [1] "here again"
#> [1] "return block x=  2"
#> [1] "here again"
#> [1] "return block x=  1"
#> [1] "here again"
#> [1] 1 5

recur2 <- function(x, y) {
  # 1st code block
  if (x < y) {
    print(paste('before',x)) # 1st print statement to check control flow
    x <- x + 1
    x <- recur2(x, y)
  }
  
  # 2nd code block
  print(paste('return block',x)) # 2nd print statement to check control flow
  return (x)
}
recur2(0,5)
#> [1] "before 0"
#> [1] "before 1"
#> [1] "before 2"
#> [1] "before 3"
#> [1] "before 4"
#> [1] "return block 5"
#> [1] "return block 5"
#> [1] "return block 5"
#> [1] "return block 5"
#> [1] "return block 5"
#> [1] "return block 5"
#> [1] 5

Created on 2024-11-16 with reprex v2.1.1
